# How to access artifacts from previous last run to current run of same job in gitlab..?

Tags: gitlab

My actual requirement is I want to upload a file in gitlab artifacts with some data generated on run time for a specific job (even job got success or fail). If job got failed then I'll retry that particular job and I want to access the data in that file uploaded in artifacts in previous run. Can you please suggest some way on how to do this.